# Check if list of users has access to list of account records

Tags: apex, soql, sharing, dynamic-soql, userrecordaccess

Before Creating an accountShare record I need to check first if the user has access to the related record
I am well aware that I can get it done using the UserRecordAccess Object

```
select RecordId, HasReadAccess, HasEditAccess, HasDeleteAccess
from UserRecordAccess
where UserId = '00550000001J0oE'
and RecordId in ('0015000000cura9AAA', '0035000001C44pO')
```

But If I use it in a for loop that loop through the users ids, I d get a limit error
and It would be a bad practice anyway

Any suggestions on how I can achieve my goal ?

Every help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the documentation of [UserRecordAccess](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_userrecordaccess.htm), you can have only a single `Id` when filtering by `UserId`. This prevents checking in one SOQL query record access for multiple users. You need to work with `CustomObject__Share` records.

Let's say, that you need to check, that record of `CustomObject__c` is readable for users.

1. Check if it is not `Public Read/Write` owd for the object. If it is `Public Read/Write` object `CustomObject__Share` will not exist in org at all.
2. Check if the user has checked permissions `View All`, `Modify All`on the object,  `View All Data` and `Modify All Data`, as it is not tracked in the `Share` object.
3. Finally query share records

Here is some old code in [GitHub](https://github.com/Pexlify/Auto-Followup-Records/blob/master/src/classes/SharingAccessChecker.cls), which could be helpful for you.